# C# WPF Print to file without user interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, msdn

I'm trying to write a program that should be able to create files that can be sent to a selected printer.
At this moment, the code is as follow

```
Canvas c = GetMyCanvas();
PrintDialog p = new PrintDialog();
PrintQueue printQueue = GetPrintQueues("Printer1"); //this printer is configured as Print To File
PrintTicket printTicket = GetPrintTicket(printQueue);
        
//Create a fixed Document and Print the document
FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
fixedPage.Height = 11.69 * 96;
fixedPage.Width = 8.27 * 96;

fixedPage.Children.Add(c);
((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(".\\xpsDocTest.xps", FileAccess.Write);
XpsDocumentWriter xWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
xWriter.Write(fixedDoc, printTicket);
xpsDoc.Close();

printQueue.AddJob("prova", ".\\xpsDocTest.xps", false);
```

The problem is that the `AddJob` function (that creates the output file) shows a dialog asking for the user to specify the name of the output file.
This behavior was expected, as Microsoft said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/documents/how-to-print-xps-files?view=netdesktop-5.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> To avoid the Save Output File As dialog when adding a print job to the default queue, ensure that your default printer isn't Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Microsoft Print to PDF, or other print-to-file options

Unfortunately, I need to use every kind of printer (printer to file in particular) without asking for any additional information from the user.
Is there a way to set the output file name programmatically?
Are there alternatives to the use of XPSDocument API and AddJob functions?

Comment: Can I ask why you doens't save the file yourself in case of  printer to file?

Comment: Which file you are referring to? I can obtain the correct file format (for example a postscript file) only after AddJob function. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In your question you stated *I'm trying to write a program that should be able to create files that can be sent to a selected printer*

Comment: @StefanoCavion ok, I get the point. I need to store the files and print them later following a different order.

Comment: @KJ Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my question or I didn't undertand your comment. The funtcion `AddJob` creates the correct file for each printer (using the driver of the printer, I think) but this function show the dialog asking for the name of the output file. I want to hide this dialog and set output file programmatically. Using GDI I could use the `DOCINFO` struct inside `StartJob` but I would like to avoid to use GDI.

Comment: @frankborty yes that is what I meant ;)

Comment: You could use a virtual printer and configure it to produce the desired output. As an example, the [LEADTOOLS ePrint](https://www.eprintdriver.com/) virtual printer (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor) can be preconfigured to silently accept print jobs and save the output to multiple formats using the print job name.